# OpenCL get_global_id with wrong result

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl

I have a problem with wrong `global_id()` result. I would like to convolute 3D voxel with dimension `{35,35,35}` with 3D kernel with dimension `{5,5,5}`. Therefore, I call "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel" with `global_size = {35,35,35}` and `local size = { 5, 5, 5}`

```
std::vector<size_t> local_nd  = { 5, 5, 5 };
std::vector<size_t> global_nd = { 35, 35, 35 };
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( queue, hello_kernel, work_dim, NULL, global_nd.data(), local_nd.data(), 0, NULL, NULL);
```

What I expect when I call `get_global_id()` function is 
the `global_id(0)` should be between 0 to 34
`global_id(1)` should be between 0 to 34
and `global_id(2)` should be between 0 to 34.

However for `global_id(0)` `and global_id(1)` the results seem correct.
However the `global_id(2)` the values range from 30 - 34 instead of
0 to 34 that I expect.

```
const int  ic0     =  get_global_id(0);  // icol
const int  ic1     =  get_global_id(1);  // irow  
const int  ic2     =  get_global_id(2);  // idep 


printf(" %d %d %d\n", ic0, ic1, ic2 ); 
// value of ic0 = [0  -> 34] correct!
// value of ic1 = [0  -> 34] correct!
// value of ic2 = [30 -> 34]  ( SHOULD IT BE [0->34] )?
```

my gpu is max-workgroup is max work-group item ND: { 1024, 1024, 64 }

Comment: Maybe you have a race condition. Show your kernel code.

Comment: `printf` in kernels isn't always reliable - there's often a fixed-size buffer, and if you output too much, some messages may be dropped. Try getting each work item to write an element in a 3D array and inspect that instead, or constrain the range on printfs (`if (ic2 < 10) printf(…);`) to show that the earlier ones are being hit.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem as pmdj suggested.

```
printf in kernels isn't always reliable - there's often a fixed-size buffer, and if you output too much, some messages may be dropped.
```

After I changed the OpenCL code with some conditions. ex:

```
if( ic2< 10 )
    printf("ic2: %d ", ic2 );
```

The output ranges from [0 --> 34 as I expected]